# Update table Error Using Convert Function In SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with two columns, all of them are datetime value
Such as, Column A with value ‘07/09/2012 14:13:34’
Now, I want to update column A to yyyymmdd by statement

```
 Update Change_Date
    SET A = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),A,112)
```

It shows succsessful message but with no effect (no update value to 20120907) in my table Change_Date.

Any help will be greated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A datetime fields saves a date time. How you *see* that date time is a result of the tool you're using to inspect the data, whether it is Management Studio, or your own software that's printing something from the database.

I strongly recommend keeping it as a datetime field. This will allow you to do date-related operations, such as subtractions and comparisons. If you want to change how your users see the date, then format your date at the presentation layer.

What's happening in the code you've posted is that you're setting the value of `A` to the same date that it already is. The fact that you're setting that value by means of a string in another format has no relation, SQL server will always have to parse your string input into a date that it can understand. This is why you're not getting an error message. The operation is working, only it's not changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the datatype of the column is `DATE` or `DATETIME` and it has specific format. If you want to update the column with specific format, make another column and make its datatype `VARCHAR`. I believe `112` is `yyyymmdd` format.

I strongly suggest that you keep it AS IS. Database is the storage of data and not for viewing purposes. It is easy to perform task for dates if your data type is `DATETIME` or `DATE`. If for instance you want to retrieve the dates with specific format, that's the time you convert your date.

Hope this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you meant this: "It's because the datatype of the column is `DATE` or `DATETIME` and it has **no** specific format"?

Comment: No you didn't. I was asking if you meant to say that. Because a date or datetime column *doesn't* really have a specific format.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the date column in specified format or make a view which selects the column value in yyyymmdd format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), A, 112) FROM Change_Date
```